# What word describes languages that are written left-to-right, top-to-bottom?

Tags: word-choice, names

I am trying to describe the set of languages that, like English, are written left to right, and was trying "romanized", but "romanized" describes transliteration to a different set of characters, such as taking the Japanese word `着物` and writing it as `kimono` in English.

Unfortunately, when I enter "left to right" in a Google query, it finds me all the pages with "right to left" in them, which is of course the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: For all the scholarly articles on laterality caused by directionality, you'd think there was a name but I couldn't find it. I hope someone answers this definitively.

Comment: I've only ever seen them referred to as _ltr_ and _ttb_. Note that this is a feature of the **script** (more precisely the **writing style**), though, not the language. Turkish is written left to right currently, but less than a century ago, the official Turkish orthography was right to left, using the Arabic script. Japanese is usually written ttb-rtl in books and newspapers, but in comics, many magazines, and regular office documents and such things (as well as online), it's ltr-ttb. And Chinese can be ltr-ttb, ttb-rtl, or rtl-ttb, depending on context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I've been reading about the cognitive effect of directionality of writing which are huge. One would thing (no pun intended) that something so influential in our thinking, spatial imaging, etc. would have a more dignified name that ltr ttb. It even affected how people thought about *writing one's thoughts*; the Ancient Greeks, Chinese and Egyptians had different concepts in part based on the cognitive impact of directionality (I didn't reach the Hebrews yet).

Comment: @medica There should be, shouldn't there? But the only actual term I can think of (or rather, had to google my way to because I annoyingly _couldn't_ think of it!) is only really a term, I think, because it refers to a type of directionality we _don't_ use/reckon with: the [boustrophedon](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Wow! Thanks. I bet neuroscientists would have a field day studying people who wrote boustrophedonically. Amazing.

Comment: @medica Alas, I fear they'd have to be forensic neuroscientist archaeologists for the opportunity to arise. :-)

Comment: Thought I'd point out that the CSS spec has [standardized names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) for a few combinations of properties.  As elsewhere, they're just abbreviations of phrases.

Comment: Continuing starwed's comment, [because I was going to mention also], there are values called "lr-tb" and currently "horizontal-tb" for "writing-mode" property in CSS and XML. I don't believe there is a specific name in linguistics. It is a type of directionality as mentioned before.

Comment: Usually *romanization* refers to the transcription of spoken language into the Roman alphabet rather than transliteration of another writing system, although both are possible.  For example, Hepburn romanization is based on sound rather than reproducing kana spelling.

Comment: I'd say _[sinistrodextral](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sinistrodextral)_, the obvious but wholly unpopular complement to _[dextrosinistral](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/dextrosinistral)_.  Those terms are more at home in anatomy, I think, but your use would be clear.  Can't help you with the other dimension, though.  (_craniocaudal_ is right out.)

Comment: Wrong question. There is no word for languages depending on how they are **written**. There are words for languages that depend on their pronunciation and grammar, but not for how they're written. Writing systems are independent of languages and any language can be written any way at all (not always as well, but who cares?). So you should be asking about **writing systems** that are written from left to right and others. Not languages. And you should be asking on Linguistics Stack Exchange, not here; this is specifically for English grammar and usage.

Comment: @pilcrow - Extending your suggestions of *sinistrodextral* for LTR scripts and *dextrosinistral* for RTL ones, it would be logical to use corresponding combining forms for TTB and BTT scripts like *suprainferior* (TTB) and *infrasuperior* (BTT). Nevertheless, the abbreviation-based convention has the benefit of concision for an academic paper, especially if specifying both the L-R and T-B dimensions: calling something a *"sinistrodextral infrasuperior script"* turns it into rather a mouthful. However, in speech I think the novel forms would be easier to understand than the abbreviated ones.

Answer (score 9):

They're simply referred to simply as as ***left-to-right*** or *left-to-right, horizontal* (e.g. English, Greek).

The opposite is *right-to-left*, or *right-to-left, horizontal*  (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew).

*LTR* and *RTL* are also used as abbreviations.

There's a third class which do have a good name: *boustrophedon*. These alternate left-to-right then right-to-left. The name comes from the Greek for *ox* and *turn*, because it resembles an ox pulling a plough. Another name is *plough-wise*.

And these are just the horizontal writing systems. Here's some others, listed by [Omniglot](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/direction.htm):

- Left to right, vertical, top to bottom
- Right to left, vertical, top to bottom
- Left to right, vertical, bottom to top
- Right to left, vertical, bottom to top
- Variable

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time finding anything and had to settle for using the abbreviations, RTL (right to left) and TTB (top to bottom).

Normal Google didn't return anything useful using ["left to right" -"right-to-left], neither did Google Scholar, although there are some quite nice papers on the effect of writing direction on the mind.

If this is academic writing, try to stick what the others in the field have been using, what I have found in this [article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/713754473), is that the author sticks to just using "left to right" and "right to left", so without any specific term.

If anyone is able to find a source for a more specific word, I would be very interested.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once when I compared Arabic letters and Latin letters in order to see whether there was a relationship and, of course, I wanted an adjective. At last I used rechtsläufig and linksläufig in German, that would be right-running and left-running scripts. But I think the abbreviations rtl-/ltr-scripts will do as well.